# Locating known Bluetooth devices in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a list of known Bluetooth device addresses, and would like to know which ones are in proximity. Scanning each in turn is far too slow. I don't want to force the devices to be discoverable, since this requires a user prompt that breaks my workflow.

Is there a way to efficiently determine which of a set of Bluetooth devices are in proximity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Scanning each in turn is far too slow.

Does this mean attempting to connect to each one is far to slow? I think that besides making the other devices discoverable this is the only way you are going to be able to do it. To oversimplify a bit: in order for you to know what devices are out there, you need to send a message to them and get a response. When you get a list of discoverable devices in proximity, you are basically sending out a general request for a response. Devices that are not discoverable won't reply to this request, so in order to find them you need to send a message to each one individually.

Comment: I heard a rumor that devices that are bonded may show up during discovery, even if they are not discoverable. I haven't had a chance to test this out yet, but will report back. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: No such luck, I think you are right that the remote device has to be discoverable, even if the mac is known. There doesn't seem to be a way to have a device discoverable only for bonded devices, which is what I'm after.

Comment: If the devices are paired, you can attempt to make a connection regardless of whether the other device is discoverable. To see which of your other devices are in range you could attempt to make a connection with each one. I don't think this is very processor intensive, so you could run each attempt in a separate thread and avoid a huge performance hit.